# plot with multi colors matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, and have some difficult to generate a "Multi Color" graph.
I'm reading data from a text file into three vectors: X, Y and Cluster.
I need to generate a graph for X and Y and to set the color of the point according to the cluster {0,1,2}.
Can you please advise how can I do that? From what I tried to do, it only gives me an option to draw a plot by X,Y with one color.

Thanks in advance,
Adi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do a scatter plot

```
cmp = lines(3);
scatter( X, Y, 20, cmp(Cluster+1), 'filled');
```

note the `+1` when indexing `cmp` - Matlab's first index is **1** and **not** 0!

Comment: You can also write: `scatter( X, Y, 20, Cluster, 'filled');colormap(lines(3));` to obtain the same result. Using indexed colors allows you to specify any numeric input for the color argument in `scatter`.